# Is there a way to set the limits on the y axis in python (Matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python (v 3.7) and currently working on preprocessing pupil data. I am working with the following code:

```
    x = np.arange(timepoints.shape[0])/sample_rate
    f = pl.figure(figsize = (10,3.5))
    pl.plot(x, pupil)
    pl.xlabel('Time (s)')
    pl.ylabel('Pupil size')
    sn.despine(offset=10)
```

Using the above code, I receive the following output:

[image]
I would like the y-axis limits to be within the range of 0-1000. I have tried `ylim` and this does not seem to work and I still receive the same output.

Here is the new figure with the following code:

```
     x = np.arange(timepoints.shape[0]) / sample_rate
     f = pl.figure(figsize = (15,3.5))
     pl.plot(x, pupil)
     pl.yticks(np.linspace(0, 1000, 10))
     pl.xlabel('Time (s)')
     pl.ylabel('Pupil size (a.u)')
     sn.despine(offset=10)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jijiA.png)

I've tried playing around with the numbers etc. but it still doesn't seem to cooperate.

Comment: In order to understand why ylim does not work, could you provide some data? Did you use ylim is this format: pl.ylim(0, 1000) ?

Comment: Yes, I used pl.ylim(0,1000) but as you can see in the image the values appear squashed together. I'm not entirely sure how to fix the values on the y-axis

Comment: Oh so you don't need to change the range, but the tick spacing on the y axis. Try this: pl.yticks(np.linspace(0,1000,10))

Comment: I've just tried that and it is less squashed but the values are not what I enter e.g. if I enter pl.yticks(np.linspace(0,1000,10)), the y axis starts from 800 - 900 and it starts in the middle of the axis?

Comment: Can you post the new figure?

Comment: Just edited the original post with the new figure... The numbers seem to have changed

Comment: Sorry I don't see a new photo, but just the one with the numbers squashed together.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this so I'm not sure whether I have attached it correctly. Can you go onto the link in the original post which states 'enter image description here'?

Comment: Oh sorry I see it now. I don't know. With simulated data: x = np.arange(0, 1000)
pupil = np.random.random(x.shape) *1000 I get a correct plot using your second code. If you can share data maybe we'll track the issue, otherwise I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

If you would have googled it before, it would be better. There is a way to do it,

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html

Check it out!

Comment: Tried that too. I still arrive at the same output.